# Disk performance between servers in NFS directory

Tags: nfs, performance, io, gzip

I am having a two linux server set up.
ServerA has /apps/data.
ServerB has mounted on `/data` ServerAs path `/apps/data` with `NFS`.
How load of various operations is handled? by meaning:
Q:
By initiating gzip for example (could be cp as second example) on ServerB the I/O is handled by ServerA or ServerB
How disks perform? meaning ServerB gets the file to his disk to perform the gzip then place it back to NFS and it sync over the network? (IO increase of both servers + network traffic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a directory shared over NFS from `ServerA` and mounted by `ServerB`.

If you perform a file operation in that directory on `ServerB`, there will be no disk I/O happening on `ServerB`, but there will be network I/O between the servers, and `ServerA` will eventually perform the actual disk operations (by instructions from the NFS daemon).

The file you are accessing will not be transferred between the servers as if synchronized with `rsync` or `scp`, but chunks of the file will be transferred over NFS and handed directly to the process that reads the data, as it reads it, or to the server for writing to disk as needed. This is happening using the NFS protocol as described by [RFC 1094](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1094) (NFSv2) or [RFC 1813](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813) (NFSv3).

Again, there will be *no* disk operations on `ServerB`, unless it needs swap or if whatever it is you're doing allocates space in a non-NFS-mounted directory (e.g. `/tmp`).

In fact, `ServerB` might very well exist without *any* physical disk connected at all.  This is called a ["diskless system"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskless_node) and used to be popular in the computer labs where I first encountered Unix in the early 90's (on [Sun SPARCstation IPCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARCstation_IPC) that had a local `/tmp` but everything else mounted via NFS).

Working over NFS will be slower than working against a local disk due to the network I/O, but for day-to-day command line work it hardly matters much unless you regularly handle large amounts of data on file.